# Renaming Bulk JPG Images & Formating - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, format, rename, bulk

So I've pretty much finished what I inteneded on doing. I want to format a bunch of images in a folder to a specific format of "Picture 0000" but when I get to the tenth picture the format goes "Picture 00010"

How do I tell it to subtract one 0 when it hits 10, when it hits 100 and when it hits 1000.

Here is my current code:

```
dir | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "Picture 000$x.jpg"; $x++ }
```

Thank you,
Appletatoes

```
dir | %{$x=0001} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "Picture $x.jpg"; $x++ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an index counter, loop through the files and rename them using the formatted counter. Increment that counter at the same time.

Something like this

```
$i = 0
Get-Childitem -Path 'THE FOLDER WHERE THE IMAGES ARE' -Filter '*.jpg' -File | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('Picture {0:0000}.jpg' -f $i++) 
}
```

Comment: How can I execute this in PowerShell? Or can I make a script with this in it?

Comment: @Appletoes I don't really understand... This **is** PowerShell. Just paste it in the ISE editor, change the path to where your pictures are and run it.

Comment: Okay it worked but when it gets to file 1112 the next one goes 10000, 10001, 10002, etc...

Comment: Jessen above mentioned making 0:0000 to 0:00000 but I need the format to stay 4 decimal places please.

Comment: @Appletoes Please refresh the explorer you're looking at and if needed resort by Name. The 4 digit format will go up to 9999. After that it will become 10000 of course. If you have that many files, use a 5 or 6 digit format {0:00000}

Comment: Thank you and my last question would be how do I automate this to make this a script I can double click and execute with admin rights? I don't want to have to run the script when PowerShell ISE opens. Thank you.

Comment: @Appletatoes Just save it as 'RenamePictureFiles.ps1' file for instance. However, a script is NOT an executable. It has to be run by the PowerShell interpreter, either `powershell.exe` or `PowerShell_ISE.exe`. You can make a shortcut to the file on your desktop, remember the path where you saved it and change the `TargetPath` to become `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "X:\RenamePictureFiles.ps1"`. Next click the `Advanced` button and set the checkmark for `Run as Administrator`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am just getting a small error that I think I figured out how to get by but I'm not sure where to add it in the code. I'm getting an execution of scripts is disabled on the system and I found the code '-ExecutionPolicy ByPass' that I want to add in but could you help me with where that needs to go please?

Comment: @Appletatoes Just put it in right before the `-File` parameter. That'll work.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I did get it to work by making a batch file and have it pointed to the RenamePictureFiles.ps1. Here is the batch file script I made: @echo off powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Folder\RenamePictureFiles.ps1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-f` string format operator to add leading zeros to a number:

```
dir | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Picture {0:0000}.jpg' -f $x); $x++ }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with that:

Rename-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1++'.
At line:1 char:16
+ dir | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Picture {0:0000}.jpg' -f $x) $x++ }
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: Put a semicolon before the $x++.  `dir | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Picture {0:0000}.jpg' -f $x) -whatif; $x++ }`  I added a -whatif to try it out.

Comment: Or just `dir | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Picture {0:0000}.jpg' -f $x++) } `

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what {0:0000} is doing?

Comment: Also, I got it to run perfectly now but I want to make a .PS1 script that I can just double click to run. If I make a specific folder to put these images in and name its path, how would I incorporate it into the following code:

dir | %{$x=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Picture {0:0000}.jpg' -f $x++)}

Comment: If you could try this script for yourself, I notice it doesn't work very well with anything over 1000 files in a folder. Could you help me out with that? Thank you!

Comment: Change it up to `{0:00000}` in stead of `{0:0000}`

Comment: Tried that but it seems to be stuck in a loop. It keeps renaming and renaming.